# Need Help Slicing & Indexing Nested List with Python

Tags: python, nested-lists

Haven't used Python in a few months and I'm struggling to figure out how I can slice & index nested lists.

So, I was reading [Scikit-Learn's Getting Started Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/getting_started.html). I'll use their code in this post for a better interpretation of what I'm trying to do.

Our Sample Matrix ("Nested List")

```
X = [[ 1,  2,  3],  # 2 samples, 3 features
     [11, 12, 13]]
```

I'm looking to return a list containing **every sample's** *first feature*.

```
X[:][0]
[1, 2, 3]
```

***Confused*** That's not what I expected. Even weirder... Switching the index values around returned the same thing.

```
X[0][:]
[1, 2, 3]
```

**What the heck am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: Just to be clear, you expected `[1, 11]`, right?

Comment: If you copy the matrix and then take the first row, you get the first row. How is that weird?

Comment: `[y[0] for y in x]`. Doesn’t require practicing every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you expected `[1, 11]`, I think you're thinking of [NumPy array slicing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(X)
print(a[:,0])  # -> [ 1 11]
```

In plain Python, there's no way to do it without looping, for example:

```
print([x[0] for x in X])  # -> [1, 11]
```

Using `[:]` on a list just makes a copy of it.

Comment: Do you consider the NumPy one to be "without looping"? How about `[*[*zip(*X)][0]]` then?

Comment: @Kelly Yeah, cause there's no explicit "for". I'm aware that it's probably implemented using a loop under the hood. Now for the `zip` option, firstly I'd write it as `list(next(zip(*X)))`. Yeah, `zip` obviously loops under the hood, but I wouldn't recommend that cause it's so contrived.

Comment: Maybe change "no way" to "no nice way"? :-)

Comment: @Kelly It's not really important to the question. But either way, `zip` does loop, just implicitly. Meanwhile, how NumPy applies a vector operation is an implementation detail.